# Sequences with terms that have multiple values

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$u_{n-1}=u_n(2.5(u_n\text{ mod }2) + 0.5) + (u_n\text{ mod }2)\text{ where }u_1 = 1$$
is the [Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), where $n$ is how far away $u_n$ is from $1$. For example, take $u_n=20$. Then the number before it in the Collatz Conjecture is $20/2=10$. Then:$$u_{n-1}=20(2.5(20\text{ mod }2)+0.5)+(20\text{ mod }2)\\=20(2.5(0)+0.5)+0\qquad\qquad\quad\ \\=20(0.5)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ \ \\=10\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ \ $$This works for odd numbers too (I adapted it from Python, so It won't be as simplified as posible). The thing is, this looks like a sequence, but some terms have multiple values. To illustrate:$$u_1=1,\\u_2=2,\\u_3=4,\\\qquad\ u_4=\{1,\ 8\},\\\qquad\ \ \ u_5=\{2,\ 16\},\\\qquad\qquad u_6=\{4,\ 5,\ 32\},\\\qquad\qquad\ \ u_7=\{1,\ 10,\ 64\},\\\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad u_8=\{2,\ 3,\ 20,\ 21,\ 128\},\\\dots\quad\ $$Is it still a sequence? Or is it something else? And how do you show the terms, do you use sets (like I did)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sets is an appropriate way to do this; it's a sequence, yes, but it's a sequence *of sets* (of finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ to be specific). You'd want to use singleton sets - i.e. $u_1=\{1\}$ instead of $u_1=1$, though.
You could define an $f$ such that
$$u_{n-1}=f(u_n)$$
and then the most standard way to talk about this would be to set:
$$u_0=\{1\}$$
$$u_{n+1}=f^{-1}[u_n]$$
where the notation $f^{-1}[S]$ means "the preimage of $S$" - the set of points mapping into $S$. A common notation would even be to write $u_n=f^{-n}[\{1\}]$, which would be the $n^{th}$ preimage of $\{1\}$.